# mongodb: how to find a given record's index with a specifed order?

Tags: algorithm, mongodb

I have records with:

```
User id, reputation
1      ,  5
2      ,  8
3      ,  2
4      ,  6
```

For User id 2, I want to get the user's reputation and the index of the record using descend ordering of reputation. In this example the index of user 2 is 1, the index of user 4 is 2, etc.

I want the algorithm can process many users(10K at least), so the performance is a concern, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse sort by `reputation`

```
db.users.find().sort({"reputation":-1})
```

For performance of this query, create an index on reputation as:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({"reputation":-1})
```

Comment: How to get the index of user id 2, in the set of reverse sort of "reputation"?

Comment: Do that in the programming language of your choice. Its a data store, not an API. Its fairly simple to iterate over a list and keep a track of the index.

Comment: No, thats why you paginate through them. Iterating over 10K records is going to be an issue regardless of NoSQL or RDBMS.